# Getting the link, not the anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, html-helper

I'd like to write:

```
 <a href='@Html.LinkGenerator'>Edit</a>
```

instead of:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")
```

Where @Html.LinkGenerator is the name of an imaginary helper which only creates the link, not the whole anchor tag, for a given route and action.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) helper which is not imaginary but very real and does what you need:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit")">Edit</a>
```